# What controls a device controller?

Tags: drivers

My theory is that a device driver is the one that controls a device controller which in turn controls a hardware device. Is this reasoning correct? Please excuse my lack of knowledge. Just reading about and stumbled onto this thought?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What controls a device controller?

The host computer (to which the device controller is connected) using device commands.

> My theory is that a device driver is the one that controls a device controller which in turn controls a hardware device.

A device driver is OS software that is executing on the host CPU.  The driver has to translate OS I/O requests and data into operations that the peripheral device can perform.

A device controller is part of a peripheral's subsystem.  The controller is considered hardware, but the typical (modern) controller has a processor (typically a microcontroller or a microprocessor), is programmed (i.e. firmware installed in nonvolatile memory, such as NAND Flash) and is essentially an embedded computer whose purpose is to provide an interface between the host computer and a device.  The device controller could be manufactured as a single IC (especially when produced in large volumes and/or due to packaging requirements) or completely integrated with a CPU in a SoC, or could be a few chips on a board.

The hardware interface of the device controller to the host computer would be a set of "device registers".  Some controllers may have an elaborate set of registers (aka ports), especially when integrated on the silicon chip with a CPU (aka SoC, System on Chip).  Other controllers that connect to the host computer through a cable typically have a HW interface that resembles a communications link (e.g. SATA, USB).

The software interface of the device controller varies.
Typically there is a set of commands which can be written to a command register.  Or there could be a data register for writing packets of a command and/or data (e.g. SATA).  These commands (e.g. perform a read or write or reset operation) are what "control" the device controller and the actual device through low-level operations.